# How to resize a JTextField within a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am just creating a simple GUI for practice I want to have a few text boxes within my JFrame but I the JTextField I created is taking up the whole frame. I tried doing .setSize but that didn't work.

JFrame

```
public static Component textbox(String x){
    JLabel lbltAm= new JLabel(x);
    JTextField tftAm = new JTextField(20);
    lbltAm.setLabelFor(tftAm);
    lbltAm.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    tftAm.setSize(10, 10);
    return tftAm;
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    //Create and set up the window.


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tip Calculator");
    //Add Textbox
    frame.add(textbox("TipAmmount"));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 400));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Try creating a FlowLayout and put your JTextField and your JLabel inside the layout. and Add your layout to the JFrame

Comment: `new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18)` would best be `new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 18)` for compile time checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not using any layout I suggest to use FlowLayout and GridBagLayout.

Comment: JFrame has BorderLayout as default LayoutManager in API

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning  JTextField return a Panel object and add the JTextField and Jlabel Object into the panel.You can use any layout I've used BorderLayout

```
public static Component textbox(String x){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel lbltAm= new JLabel(x);
    JTextField tftAm = new JTextField(20);
    lbltAm.setLabelFor(tftAm);
    lbltAm.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    tftAm.setSize(10, 10);
    panel.add(lbltAm, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(tftAm, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return panel;
}
```

There are multiple layout using which you can layout components in a Panel. [have a look](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Its not a good practice to add components directly to JFrame 
use it like this

> frame.getContentPane().add(component)

or if using borderlayout you can add like this

> frame.getContentPane().add(compnent, BorderLayout.CENTER);